# Does there exist a basis of a Convex Cone

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, vector-spaces, convex-analysis, convex-geometry

We are given a set $C \subset V$, where $V$ is a vector space. $C$ is a convex cone, so it has the following properties

$$
0 \in C
$$

$$
C+C \in C
$$

$$
x\cdot C\in C\mid x\in\mathbb{R} \land x\geq0
$$

My question is, does there exist a set of basis vectors that spans this convex cone and only this convex cone (no vector in the span is not in the cone)?

I'm also trying to practice my math notation, so here's the above statement rewritten

Does

$$
\exists B=\{\vec b_1, \vec b_2, \ldots, \vec b_n\} \mid \operatorname{span}(B) = C \implies c_1\vec b_1 + \cdots +c_n\vec b_n \in C \forall c_k\in \mathbb{R_+}
$$

Comment: If the span of $B$ is $C$, then $C$ is a subspace?

Comment: If I understand correctly, it sounds like you are asking if any convex cone is finitely generated. The answer to this question is no. Try Googling finitely generated cones / polyhedral cones. Also, since you’re working on your math notation, I think you mean $C+C=C$, not $C+C\in C$ (the latter statement does not make sense).

Comment: @DavidM. the second order cone in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is not finitely generated, but you can take an appropriately chosen circle as the (infinite) set of basic vectors.

Comment: Or $C + C \subseteq C$ (they are equivalent assuming $0 \in C$)

Comment: @LinAlg Certainly. Since the OP indexed the basis vectors $b_1,\dots,b_n$ I assumed they wanted a finite set.

Comment: @David M., a finite set would be nice, but my actual end goal was to find an orthogonal vector to the basis, so if that could be done with an infinite set it would certainly do. I have a question though, my vectors are actually multidimensional polynomials, so could that make or break my hopes of a basis set or orthogonal polynomial?

Comment: Per @max_zorn ‘s comment: do you mean span or cone (_i.e._ set of conic combinations)?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. The term span has a fairly standard meaning in context and it means the smallest linear subspace containing said set. You appear to be asking if it is finitely generated and the answer is no for the same reason a disc has an infinite number of extreme points.

Comment: So a convex cone requires an infinite basis to span it? Does there exist any vector orthogonal to all vectors in the convex cone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like we need to distinguish linear span from conical hull.

Given a set $S$ of elements of a vector space $V$ (could be the polynomials, as in your example), the *linear span* of $S$ is [defined to be](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_span#Definition)

$$ \text{span}(S)=\left\{\left.\sum_{i=1}^k\lambda_iv_i\ \right|k\in\mathbb{N},v_i\in{S},\lambda_i\in\mathbb{R}\right\}. $$

In contrast, the conical hull of $S$ is [defined to be](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conical_combination#Conical_hull):

$$ \text{cone}(S)=\left\{\left.\sum_{i=1}^k\alpha_iv_i\ \right|k\in\mathbb{N},v_i\in{S},\alpha_i\in\mathbb{R}_+\right\}. $$

The difference between these definitions is that the scalars in the conical hull must be *non-negative*.

So when you say:

> Does there exist a set of basis vectors that spans the convex cone?

you're asking

> Does there exist a set $S$ such that $\text{span}(S)=C$?

It's easy to see that $\text{span}(S)$ is a linear subspace of the vector space $V$. So the answer to the question above is yes if and only if $C$ is a linear subspace of $V$. A linear subspace is a convex cone, but there are lots of convex cones that aren't linear subspaces. So this probably isn't what you meant.

If instead, you ask

> Does there exist a set $S$ such that $\text{cone}(S)=C$?

then the answer is yes, but the set $S$ may be infinite.

Based on what you said in the comments, it sounds like you are looking for a set $S$ such that $\text{cone}(S)=C$, and a vector $v$ which is orthogonal to every element of $S$. This will only be possible if $\text{span}(C)$ is a *proper subspace* of $V$. In this case, you can take $v$ to be a vector in the orthogonal complement of $\text{span}(C)$. Otherwise, $\text{span}(C)=V$, and there is no vector which is orthogonal to every vector in $S$.

Comment: I have two doubts here. 
1) You mentioned we can find a set S such that cone(S) = C. 
How do we find it? Is there any reference? Is this set S called the base of the cone? 
2) Why we need the orthogonal vector v?