# If $X\subset \mathbb R^n$ with $(x+y),\lambda x\in X$ for all $x,y\in X$ and $\lambda \gt0$, then is $X$ the positive span of an independent system?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

***Original question***

Let $X\subset \mathbb R^n$ such that $(x+\lambda y)\in X$ for all $x,y\in X$ and $\lambda \geq 0$.

Can we find linearly independent $x_1,\dots,x_k\in X$ such that
$$
X=\text{span}_{\mathbb R_{\geq 0}}\{x_i\}=\{\sum_i \lambda_i x_i \,\vert\, \lambda_i\geq 0 \}.
$$
The answer is no.

***Revised question, through comments and answers***

What if we additionally require

1. $x+y\in X$ and $\lambda x \in X$ for all $x,y\in X, \lambda \geq 0$
2. $X$ is closed with piecewise linear boundary
3. $x\in X \wedge-x\in X \implies x=0$

[Related question: Does there exist a basis of a Convex Cone](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2839729/does-there-exist-a-basis-of-a-convex-cone)

Comment: short answer: no, because that's a conic span

Comment: @Exodd could you elaborate a little? Why is that a problem, even though we require $\lambda \geq 0$ in the assumption on $X$? (Edit: Changed every $\gt 0$ to $\geq 0$)

Comment: @Alex First of all, your $X$ doesn't include its boundary, precluding the possibility of $X = \{(x,y): x,y \geq 0\}$ for instance. Even if you allow $\lambda_i = 0$ (as you should in this case), there are convex cones that are not finitely generated; every $X$ generated as a positive span will have a polyhedral boundary

Comment: @Alex So as another example, a "round" cone like $\{(x,y,z): z > 0, x^2 + y^2 > z^2\}$ satisfies your condition on $X$ but cannot be generated as a conic span of finitely many vectors.

Comment: Thank you! What if $X$ was closed? Ah same problem! Thanks!

Comment: @Alex Regarding your edit, what exactly do you mean by a "piecewise linear boundary"? The round cone satisfies 1 and 3 for what it's worth.

Comment: @Alex An answer to the question you might be asking: the Minkowski-Weyl theorem states (or at least implies) that a convex cone is polyhedral if and only if it is finitely generated (cf. [these notes](http://www.lukoe.com/finance/quantNotes/Polyhedral_cones_.html) or [these notes](https://www.ams.jhu.edu/~abasu9/AMS_550-465/notes-without-frills.pdf)).

Comment: Yes thats perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment by *Ben Grossmann*.

The answer is no. A round cone $X=\{(x,y,z)\,\vert\, z\geq 0,\, x^2+y^2\geq z^2\}$ is a counter-example.

*Answer to the revised question:*

The Minkowski-Weyl theorem states (or at least implies) that a convex cone is polyhedral if and only if it is finitely generated (cf. [these notes](http://www.lukoe.com/finance/quantNotes/Polyhedral_cones_.html) or [these notes](https://www.ams.jhu.edu/%7Eabasu9/AMS_550-465/notes-without-frills.pdf)).

Answer (score 2):

Even in $\mathbb R^1$ it seems that $X=[1,\infty)$ satisfies this.

Alex doubts this?

If $x \ge 1$, $y\ge 1$, $\lambda \ge 0$, then $x+\lambda y \ge 1$.

Comment: How so? $2\in X$ but $(1/4)\cdot 2$ and $0\cdot 2$ are not in $X$

Comment: Ah sure, thanks! Edited it. I did not formulate it correct

Comment: Now: in $\mathbb R^1$, try $X = \mathbb R$.  A linearly independent set can have at most one element.